# Why react-native raw app is around 7mb to 8mb in size?

Tags: android, react-native

when I create a release build with a blank initial app, it creates 7~ MB in size, 
I understand the framework is using some space but this is too much to give a user for a minimum functionality

The build is combined with `armebi` and `x86` and after separating both architectures with `enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture` i end up with max 5MB in size

I just want to know the exact reason behind this kind of oversize usage,
can anybody explain me this, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These stats are of Hello world app in React Native **(7 MB)**

The release apk generated by React Native has a few classes in the **classes.dex** file that have **12193** referenced methods for this particular app. See below Image

[image: See below image for detail]

It also adds some native dependencies in the lib directory for x86 and armeabi-v7a. Adding up to around ***6.4 MB*** of dependencies in total.
[image]

See detailed article by Dharmin Majmudar [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/comparing-apk-sizes-a0eb37bb36f)